# Shell Script- Permission Denied

Tags: shell

I was trying out a very small script

```
#!/bin/sh

test="$(/home/dell/case3.3/private.key)"

echo $test
```

I call this file `test1.sh`

I try to access a file named `private.key`
Here is the permission set for the file `private.key`
`-rw-rw-r--`

Here is the permission set for the file `test1.sh`
`-rwxrwxrwx`

I have also tried to do

`chmod u+x test1.sh`

and

`chmod 755 test1.sh`

In my agony, I also tried 
`chmod 777 test1.sh`

I believe that `777` should give it all the permissions like it did ..

I don't understand what the problem is, why is there a `permission denied`

I act as the `super user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/home/dell/case3.3/private.key` is not a script, and not executable.  `$(/home/dell/case3.3/private.key)` tries to execute that file.  It's unclear what you're trying to do, but perhaps what you want is:

```
test="$(cat /home/dell/case3.3/private.key)"
echo "$test"
```

---

<sup>Edit in response to OP's comments</sup>

You don't need to save a whole file to a variable in order to simply display its contents. Instead, use:

```
cat /home/dell/case3.3/private.key
```

If, however, you *do* want to save off some *part* of the file, use `sed`, `grep`, or `awk`.  For example

```
test="$(grep 'somethingInTheFile' /home/dell/case3.3/private.key)"
echo "$test"
```

Or, you could process the file line by line:

```
while read line; do
  echo $line
done < /home/dell/case3.3/private.key
```

Comment: Is there a way to fetch the contents of the file other than that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean "fetch the contents of the file."  You can use `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, or `cat` to parse a file.

Comment: Oh no.. I have to do the `dc` ->`obase` and `ibase` since the file is too huge and it crosses the limit :(

Comment: By `Fetch` , I meant displaying the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. 

However, I will still have to

`bc << EOF
obase=10
ibase=2
$test
EOF`


This way, I will be able to cut it down. without actually pulling out a part of the file and also get an arbitrary precision calculation which I can use later on :)

Answer (score 1):

```
test="$(/home/dell/case3.3/private.key)"
```

executes the file /home/dell/case3.3/private.key before assigning it to the variable $test.  Since /home/dell/case3.3/private.key does not have the executable bit set you get the permission denied message.

For example on my linux system:

```
david@david-Mate ~ $ touch xxx
david@david-Mate ~ $ ls -l xxx
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 0 Aug  2 12:42 xxx
david@david-Mate ~ $ test="$(./xxx)"
bash: ./xxx: Permission denied
```

Comment: Thanks!. That gives me some more explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with sudo like this:

```
sudo test1.sh
```

That might work...

Comment: Sorry run: sudo ./test1.sh But that might not work if your using windows. Idk

Comment: Sorry. I don't know then. Thats really strange

Comment: I was refering to this one [link](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/server/overview)